# Find an atlas of charts on $S^2$ with certain properties

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, spherical-geometry

Find an atlas of charts on $S^2$ for which each chart preserves area, and the transition functions relating charts have derivatives with determinant 1.

I have been thinking that I should consider the projection from the sphere to the cylinder around it, as by Archimedes this map is area preserving. I am however having difficulty explicitly expressing this map as $\sigma(u,v)$. Also, I am not sure how I make the transition functions have determinant of derivative 1.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The second part of the condition (determinant 1 of transition functions) is automatically implied if the charts preserve area _and_ orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solutions is to take your favorite area preserving map of the Earth, such as [the Gall-Peters projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall%E2%80%93Peters_projection).  Restricting the domain, appropriately, this becomes a chart.

For a sphere or radius $1$, the Gall-Peters projection has the simple formula which maps a point $(\theta, \phi)$ is spherical coordinates to the point $$(x,y) = f(\theta, \phi) = (\theta, \cos(\phi)) \in \mathbb{R}^2.$$

To verify that this preserves area, note the the area form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $dx\wedge dy$.  Pulling this back by $f$, we get \begin{align*} f^\ast(dx\wedge dy) &= (f^\ast dx)\wedge (f^\ast dy) \\ &= d(f^\ast x) \wedge d(f^\ast y)\\ &= d(x\circ f)\wedge d(y\circ f)\\ &= d\theta \wedge d\cos\phi\\ &= -\sin\phi d\theta \wedge d\phi\end{align*} which is, up to sign, the usual volume form on $S^2$.

Suppose one restricts to, say, $0<\theta <2\pi$ and $0<\phi<\pi$ to get a chart.  To complete this to an atlas, first rotate the sphere about the $z$-axis half way around, and then rotate in the $xz$ plane a quarter of the way around, and then apply the same $f$.

As Henning noted in the comments, because the second chart is also area preserving, on the overlap between the two sets, the determinant is $\pm 1$.  Since the overlap is connected, verifying at one point will determine whether or not everything is orientation preserving or orientation reversing.  If reversing, modify the second chart by postcomposing with a reflection about the $x$ axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The projection on the cylinder is *not* area preserving but *angle* preserving !

Comment: Sorry, by this I mean projection from the z-axis, so for example the point $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ would be mapped to $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$

Comment: c.f. http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eOSqPHwWJX8C&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=sphere+cylinder+area+preserving&source=bl&ots=nh1RoqDZUy&sig=aiFDX71ExTnzVK4Ao3VguqSLwgQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0TFjUYmAC9LE4gTA1YCgDQ&redir_esc=y